# I want to add "Show More" link in Review Tab in product detail page in Magento 2. Only want to show 5 reviews at a time

Tags: magento2, product, review, magento2.4.1, product-review

Add "Show More" link in review on product detail page. Only want to show 5 reviews at a time.

Comment: Do you want to add load more functionality for it?

Comment: Yes, I want to show 3 reviews only and if there are more then 3 reviews then I need load more functionality to show more reviews.

Comment: If you have any idea then please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes , i will check on it and let you know asap.

Comment: In which mageto version your are working?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.4.1

Comment: Do you know that magento provides pagination and it is same works as load more in reviews?

Comment: I have shown you here , how it will look like - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/2944870. If you want like this then i can provide you code for that.

Comment: I am not able to view the screenshot. It is showing "Invalid share key".

Comment: Please check here - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/2944870?key=d7a8284efe85961733e1130900e41857

Comment: Yes, this will work for me. Please provide me the code.

Comment: Perfect. I will paste my code as an answer.

Comment: Sure. Many Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer , approve and upvote this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by overriding below file.

> Step 1: In your module please create file di.xml under path
> PackageName/Vendor/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" type="PackageName\Vendor\Block\Rewrite\Product\View\ListView" />
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create file ListView.php file under path PackageName/Vendor/Block/Rewrite/Product/View/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Vendor\Block\Rewrite\Product\View;

class ListView extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_review_list.toolbar');
        if ($toolbar) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableLimit(array(2=>2,4=>4,6=>6))->setShowPerPage(true);
            $toolbar->setCollection($this->getReviewsCollection());
            $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

You can change setAvailableLimit(array(2=>2,4=>4,6=>6)) according to your need.

Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @Shubham did you check answer? Are you done with it?

Comment: @ZealouwWeb It is working fine. I have one question... Currently there are 2 reviews in every page but I want to show 3 review in a page.
I did like this array(3=>3,6=>6,9=>9) but it doesn't help.

Comment: @ZealouwWeb I have solved the above thing. Many thanks for you time mate!!